# Why does comparing {} and [] show an error?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, javascript-objects

On my free time, I was just playing with js console, I got an unexpected error:

```
js> [] == {}
false

js> {} == []
typein:5: SyntaxError: syntax error:
```

I tried with `===`:

```
js> [] === {}
false
js> {} === []
typein:9: SyntaxError: syntax error:
```

Am thinking wrong here?

I tested this with Firefox, Chrome and jscore.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

That's because in the second case, `{}` is interpreted as a code block, rather than an object.

If you try `({}) == []` it works just fine.

```
js> ({}) == []
false
js> ({}) === []
false
```